# Parsing Geometry to Latitude, Longitude is failing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I have a table 'geocodes_raw' of locations with Latitude and Longitude values.

```
Loc_Nm || geocode_latitude || geocode_longitude
   A   ||    43.43044      ||    -80.0910793
   W   ||    43.9114523    ||    -80.0911329
   X   ||    43.9209011    ||    -80.091323
   Y   ||    43.9083203    ||    -80.0913039
   Z   ||    43.914577     ||    -80.091198
```

I have a geometry table with area names (shown below) which has been converted from Shapefile through ogr2ogr with following command.

```
ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=RBANSAL\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySpatial;trusted_connection=yes" "C:\Users\rbansal\Downloads\ELECTORAL_DISTRICT.shp" -nln "ELECTORAL_DISTRICT_NEW" -lco PRECISION=NO -progress
```

[image: ![Table2]
I need to group the Table1 locations into specific regions as per Table2. I am using a query utilizing below-mentioned snippet.

```
select * from MyDB.dbo.Spatial_Data s, MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1;
```

It returns zero records.

Question Updated:

But, when I load the same shapefile through shp2sql.exe tool. I get the following table. Please, note the difference in the beginning text under the geom column.
[image]

This time, the same query works and gives me correct results.

```
select * from MyDB.dbo.Spatial_Data s, MyDB.dbo.geocodes_raw g 
where ogr_geometry.STContains(geometry::Parse('POINT(' + CAST(g.geocode_longitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST(g.geocode_latitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')'))=1;
```

What's going wrong when I am loading the shapefile through ogr2ogr

Comment: I projected the shapefile from 5320 to 4326 and then loaded into SQL Server. Do you mean to say the projection needs to be 3347 and not 4326?

Comment: Sorry for being a noob. I have Electoral District boundary shapefiles (with EPSG: 5320) from https://www.elections.on.ca/en/voting-in-ontario/electoral-district-shapefiles/open-use-data-product-licence-agreement/download-shapefiles.html. I need to group certain locations (for which I have lat and Long values in a separate table) within those ED boundaries. Which projection do I need to have my shapefiles in? Is my query for Lat and Long with Ogr_Geometry, correct?

Comment: You should maybe turn your LAT and LON columns into a GEOMETRY column, then you could use the STIntersects function to do this, I believe...

Comment: Hi @DPSSpatial, I have got it to work through the shp2sql.exe tool, But, now this has raised a new question...what's going wrong when I am loading the shapefile through ogr2ogr CLI. I have updated my question. Please check and share your inputs.

Comment: What does STSrid and STAsText report for both tables?

Comment: In both tables, STSrid returns 4326 and STAsText returns POLYGON((.... ....)). In fact, the Spatial Results for both tables display the same map between same lat-long coordinates. The only difference is at the beginning of the geom field of the 2 tables. 0xE61000... and 0x000000...

Comment: Not sure if you really need to worry?? I haven't tried the shp2sql.exe in a very long time and would prefer to use osgeo4w - I use a python script to access the OSGeo4W .bat file and it seems to work OK - try it out if you want: https://github.com/dpsspatial/Installation-Instructions/blob/master/shp2mssql_osgeo4w.py

Comment: Thanks, @DPSSpatial. I am not worried but, just a bit perplexed and eager to find what went wrong in the earlier case as it took me 2 days to get the desired results. Also, the SHP2SQL tool is finicky at the least and needed to be retried a number of times to read the shapefile correctly.

Comment: I have QGIS 2.12.3 installed and used the OSGeo4W tool only for the ogr2ogr commands for this scenario.

Comment: shp2sql is built much differently than the osgeo4w tools - the binary representation of the spatial data is likely different for this reason (ie. microsoft tools in shp2sql)